# In proof of tangent space being a plane

Tags: differential-geometry

can someone explain why this is true?

If $\sigma$ is a surface patch of a surface $S$ and $p$ is a point on the image of $\sigma$ and if $p$ lies in the image of a curve $\gamma$ contained in $S$ say $p = \gamma(t_0)$ where $\gamma: (a,b) \to R^3$, then for some nbhd $U$ of $t_0$, there are two functions $u$ and $v$ defined on $U$ such that for all $t \in U$::

$$\gamma(t) = \sigma(u(t), v(t))$$

this is used to prove that the tangent space to a surface at a point is a plane.

thanks for help

Comment: All that's going on here is that (using the particulars of the definition of a surface patch you have) the author is taking $(u(t),v(t)) = \sigma^{-1}(\gamma(t))$.

Comment: @TedShifrin but how to we know that the image of $\gamma$ over some open nbhd lies in the image of $\sigma$?

Comment: Continuity of $\gamma$ and the fact that the image of $\sigma$ is an open set in $S$.